# Add properties to a page from a Jekyll plugin

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, octopress

Say I want to have a page with content like this:

```
<h1>{{page.comment_count}} Comment(s)</h1>
{% for c in page.comment_list %}
<div>
    <strong>{{c.title}}</strong><br/>
    {{c.content}}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

There are no variables on the page named `comment_count` or `comment_list` by default; instead I want these variables to be added to the page from a Jekyll plugin. Where is a safe place I can populate those fields from without interfering with Jekyll's existing code?

Or is there a better way of achieving a list of comments like this?

Comment: If it helps, this is the current "hack" that is being used to get those properties in, but it is dirty and not guaranteed to be compatible with future versions of Jekyll: https://github.com/IQAndreas/jekyll-static-comments/blob/master/static_comments.rb Is there a better solution to doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't presently the possibility to add these attributes without some messing with internal Jekyll stuff. We're on our way to adding hooks for `#after_initialize`, etc but aren't there yet.

My best suggestion is to add these attributes as I've done with [my Octopress Date plugin](https://github.com/parkr/blogsource/blob/master/plugins/date.rb#L49-L78) on my blog. It uses Jekyll v1.2.0's `Jekyll::Post#to_liquid` method to add these attributes, which are collected via `send(attr)` on the `Post`:

```
class Jekyll::Post

  def comment_count
    comment_list.size
  end

  def comment_list
    YAML.safe_load_file("_comments/#{self.id}.yml")
  end

  # Convert this post into a Hash for use in Liquid templates.
  #
  # Returns <Hash>
  def to_liquid(attrs = ATTRIBUTES_FOR_LIQUID)
    super(attrs + %w[
      comment_count
      comment_list
    ])
  end
end
```

`super(attrs + %w[ ... ])` will ensure that all the old attributes are still included, then collect the return values of the methods corresponding to the entries in the `String` array.

This is the best means of extending posts and pages so far.

Comment: Is this implemented yet?

Comment: I believe this doesn't work anymore, as of Jekyll 3.2.0.