# How to created sorted categories for each post in Jekyll (as Plugin; Ruby)

Tags: ruby, sorting, jekyll

I have a website using Jekyll and I want my categories to be sorted. I succeeded sorting all the categories by:

```rb
module Jekyll
  class SortedCategoriesBuilder < Generator
    safe true
    priority :high

    def generate(site)
      site.config['sorted_categories'] = site.categories.sort { |a,b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
    end   
  end
end
```

in a plugin sorted_categories.rb. This created site.sorted_categories. Now I also want sorted categories for each posting. I want to add a post.sorted_categories for each post in site.posts by adding

```rb
  for post in site.posts
    post.class.module_eval { attr_accessor :sorted_categories } 
    post.sorted_categories = post.categories.sort { |a,b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
  end
```

to the code above, but it doesn't work.

(I know how I would sort the categories directly in the posting, but I'd like to know how it works as plugin)

How do I correct the code, so that it works? Perhaps, I do not understand die internal structure of Jekyll completely, so I'm also open for other (elegant) solutions.

Answer (score 1):

By using a workaround mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320448/add-properties-to-a-page-from-a-jekyll-plugin) the following works:

```
module Jekyll
  class Post
    def sorted_categories
      self.categories.sort { |a,b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
    end

    def to_liquid(attrs = ATTRIBUTES_FOR_LIQUID)
      super(attrs + %w[
      sorted_categories
    ])
    end
  end
end
```