# Add liquid attribute for 'class Site' in jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying add a `allstuff` attribute for `class Site` like that:

```
module Jekyll
class Site
    def allstuff
        return (self.posts + self.pages)
    end

    def to_liquid(attrs = ATTRIBUTES_FOR_LIQUID)
        super(attrs + %w[
            allstuff
        ])
    end
end
```

But when I try to used it in a `.html` like that

```
{% for p in site.allstuff %}...{% endfor %}
```

It isn't work

I have written `puts "eeeeoooo"` in `allstuff` function and I have seen that it is never called.

What is the problem?

I have added others liquid attributes for `class Post` and `class Page` in the same way without any problem. I don't know what is different.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Add properties to a Site from a Jekyll plugin. Like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320448/add-properties-to-a-page-from-a-jekyll-plugin but in `site.property` instead of `page.property`